# Click Anywhere on Body and Call a Function

Tags: javascript, function

This is my html:

```
<img id="bladder" onclick="changeimage()" src="images/logo_bladder.png" />
```

and my js:

```
   <script>
    cc = 0;
    function changeimage() {
        if (cc == 0) {
            cc = 1;
            document.getElementById('bladder').src = "images/logo_bladder_b.png";
        }
        else {
            cc = 0;
            document.getElementById('bladder').src = "images/logo_bladder.png";
        }
    }
</script>
```

I would like to be able to click anywhere on body – not only on the image! – to change the image. How do I achieve that?

Comment: You need to move the click handler to an element that contains the whole region you'd like to capture the click event.

Answer (score 2):

you can try

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(body).click(function(){
      if (cc==0) 
    {   cc=1;
    document.getElementById('bladder').src="images/logo_bladder_b.png";
    }
    else
    {
        cc=0;
     document.getElementById('bladder').src="images/logo_bladder.png";
    }
    });
});
```

OR

in you `<body>` tag, add onclick event like:

```
<body onclick="changeimage()">..</body>
```

Comment: <body onclick="changeimage()">..</body> works when you click on body, but not when you click on the image. Thanks anyway

Comment: If your image is within body tag then it should work on click of image as well

Comment: asks for JS not jquery